# verilog 16x16 register file design

Tags: verilog, cpu

I am new to Verilog coding and am trying to design a 16x16 register file.

I have so far designed a 16 bit register which consists of 16 D Flip-Flops with enable. I am now trying to design the register file body, which will consist of 16 16-bit registers. The inputs are d[15:0], e[15:0], the clock, and reset. The output will be q[15:0][15:0]. How do I specify this output in Verilog?

Answer (score 0):

Your code `q[15:0][15:0]` would give you a 2d array, where each element is 1 bit. That's not what you wanted.
Code below will give you a 1d array: 16 regs, each 16 bits wide.

```
output reg  [15:0] q [15:0];
```

Note that in verilog you should unroll such array into a vector before passing it between modules. Array style ports are a SystemVerilog feature.

Comment: Verilog ports cannot be 2d arrays or unpacked. Verilog ports can be a packed vector. SystemVerilog doesn't have this rescription.